# Help...I've been asked to synthesize!

Tags: essay

I really cannot understand what a synthesis essay is :(
What are the Do and the Do not
What will make it a successful one?
What's the difference between synthesizing snd summarizing?

Comment: [Synthesis essay guide](https://study.com/academy/lesson/how-to-write-a-synthesis-essay-definition-example.html)

Comment: I'm not sure what a synthesis essay is either, it's not a term I've ever heard before. It's possible that it's a specific topic that your teacher/professor/collaborator is using. If that's the case, then whoever is teaching or writing with you would be the best person to ask. I'm not saying this because I don't want to help, but because in your specific situation, this community might not be the best people to do so.

Answer (score 2):

[Synthesis](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/synthesis) can mean:

> 2. synthesis - the combination of ideas into a complex whole

> 3. synthesis - reasoning from the general to the particular (or from cause to effect)

You are not specific about the topic of your synthesis essay, or about any of the other requirements, so take what I have to say with a grain of salt.

I am assuming that you are being asked to write about how two (or more) things or situations are similar, different, or related. Think about the commonalities between the things as well as how they are different. Then think about how the two might be combined--what kinds of compromises would need to be made to make such a synthesis (combination) work? And what would those compromises "cost" each side? Would it even be worth it?